# SQL Server Query - Count on same table twice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This problem has been sending me insane, although admittedly I've not written SQL for a long time.

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Entities].[Events](
[EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EventVenueID] [int] NULL,
[EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
[OrganisationID] [int] NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
[DateStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DateFinish] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[MinimumProviders] [int] NOT NULL,
[MinimumAttendees] [int] NOT NULL,
[ShowCalendar] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [Entities].[EventParticipants](
[ParticipantID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ParticipantType] [int] NOT NULL,
[ParticipantStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
[AttendanceStatus] [int] NULL)
```

And a query:

```
SELECT
e.EventID,
ev.VenueName,
e.EntityID,
o.Name AS 'Organisation',
e.Title,
e.DateStart,
e.DateFinish,
e.Notes,
e.MinimumProviders,
e.MinimumAttendees,
e.CreationDate,
COUNT(epp.ParticipantID) AS 'ProvidersConfirmed',
COUNT(epa.ParticipantID) AS 'AttendeesConfirmed',
e.IsEnabled
  FROM
Entities.Events e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.EventVenues ev
  ON
e.EventVenueID = ev.EventVenueID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.Organisations o
  ON
e.OrganisationID = o.OrganisationID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.EventParticipants epp
  ON
e.EventID = epp.EventID AND epp.ParticipantType = 1 AND epp.ParticipantStatus = 3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.EventParticipants epa
  ON
e.EventID = epa.EventID AND epa.ParticipantType = 2 AND epa.ParticipantStatus = 3
  GROUP BY
e.EventID,
ev.VenueName,
e.EntityID,
o.Name,
e.Title,
e.DateStart,
e.DateFinish,
e.Notes,
e.MinimumProviders,
e.MinimumAttendees,
e.CreationDate,
e.IsEnabled
```

The count is producing strange results, for example in the EventParticipants table I have the following data:

Participant Type = 1 (3 records)
Participant Type = 2 (1 record)
Participant Status = 3 (4 records)

The queries count should return:

ProvidersConfirmed = 3
AttendeesConfirmed = 1

However, it's returning

ProvidersConfirmed = 3
AttendeesConfirmed = 3

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want but you could try to count the distinct values instead. `COUNT(distinct epp.ParticipantID)`and `COUNT(epa.ParticipantID)`. It might do what you want.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT...` would work but it would likely yield a better query plan to only join to `EventParticipants` once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all your joins are throwing off this query. When you join from `Event` to `EventParticipants` There is one event record and three EventParticipant records, this equates to three duplicate eventIDs in your dataset. Then you join to `EventParticipants` again. Because you're joining 3 rows with one row, you get the result repeated 3 times.

There are ways to trim down the results, but it would probably be better to only `JOIN` once and do some selective math in your aggregate, like this:

```
SELECT
e.EventID,
ev.VenueName,
e.EntityID,
o.Name AS 'Organisation',
e.Title,
e.DateStart,
e.DateFinish,
e.Notes,
e.MinimumProviders,
e.MinimumAttendees,
e.CreationDate,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ep.ParticipantType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'ProvidersConfirmed',
COUNT(CASE WHEN ep.ParticipantType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'AttendeesConfirmed',
e.IsEnabled
  FROM
Entities.Events e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.EventVenues ev
  ON
e.EventVenueID = ev.EventVenueID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.Organisations o
  ON
e.OrganisationID = o.OrganisationID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
Entities.EventParticipants epp
  ON
e.EventID = epp.EventID AND epp.ParticipantStatus = 3
  GROUP BY
e.EventID,
ev.VenueName,
e.EntityID,
o.Name,
e.Title,
e.DateStart,
e.DateFinish,
e.Notes,
e.MinimumProviders,
e.MinimumAttendees,
e.CreationDate,
e.IsEnabled
```

And SQL's `COUNT` will throw away all the null values so it will only count unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT epp.ParticipantID) AS 'ProvidersConfirmed',
COUNT(DISTINCT epa.ParticipantID) AS 'AttendeesConfirmed'
```

Closer, but this will still count NULL values, hence....

```
COUNT(DISTINCT epp.ParticipantID) 
     - MAX(CASE WHEN epp.ParticipantID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
     AS 'ProvidersConfirmed',
COUNT(DISTINCT epa.ParticipantID)
     - MAX(CASE WHEN epa.ParticipantID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     AS 'AttendeesConfirmed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `Left Outer Join`

Because `Left Outer Join` will select all the rows from left table. I guess this is the problem, all rows are being selected at one point from Event Participants.

You might wanna use `INNER` join if using `Outer` is not requirement.